# How to link a foreign subdomain to my webspace

Tags: domain-name-system

Ok, I'm completely new to this server stuff.

I have a client who already has a website and wants a microsite on one of their subdomains. Also, they want us to host the content.

So `sub.client.com` should link to a folder on my webspace **hosted at 1&1**.
We came as far as adding the A-record to the client's subdomain and now `sub.client.com` and `myownsite.com` both lead to the same IP.
Of course, `myownsite.com` displays the regular content, but `sub.client.com` just displays a 404.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to go on.
Where can I configure the server to use a folder on my webspace or to display anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create virtualhost entry for the doamin "sub.client.com" on your web server having same document root as you have for myownsite.com. Contact your web hosting provider and ask them to update this.